# replacing Null Values with another column values

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is how can I get the Nulls in my parent column to say whats in my BusinessLine  column..

```
  Parent     BusinessLine               Team            AgentName
  NULL    Member Service                NULL           Hay,Kelly
  NULL    Member Service                NULL           Towson,Travis
  NULL    Member Service                NULL           Wein,Kenny
  NULL    Member Service             CPO Staff         Clark,Jessica
 Resource     HR                          A            Bains, Randi
 Resource     HR                          A           Christian,Beth
 Resource     HR                          A           Carter,Jessie
 Resource     HR                          A           Cline,Sara
 Resource     HR                          A            Coleman,Nina
```

Comment: By setting them to the value of the businessline column if they're null. Though this is pretty much a textbook [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try posting about the problem you're actually having, not your attempted solution to it.

Comment: kindly mention exact issue

Comment: I concur with previous comments. A simple update will accomplish what you are looking for, but I doubt that's your real problem.

Comment: Hint:  `COALESCE()`.